# Alternate to Jayrock's ExportToString

Tags: json, .net-4.0, jayrock

I am using `Jayrock.Json.Conversion.JsonConvert.ExportToString(myObj);` and the resulting string converts the first character of the property name to a lower case. So, if I had `FirstName` as the property of `myObj`, the resulting string has `firstName`

This doesn't sit nicely with a jquery template I am using that has an alternate data source with upper case first character property names.

I understand that they introduced `JsonMemberNameAttribute` that may take care of this issue, but I was wondering if there's an alternate json serializer.

PS: I am using .NET 4.0

Comment: Are you asking about an alternate way to do this using Jayrock, or an alternative to Jayrock entirely?

Comment: @NT3RP I am open to both ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` serializer and it works as expected.